# Call to undefined function exif_imagetype()

Tags: php, image, file-upload, upload, mime-types

I am trying to get `Mime-Type` for `image-types` as follow:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']) && $_FILES['uploadfile']['error'] == 0){    

    $file = $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($file));

    switch($file_type){

        // Codes Here

    }

}
```

But it always gives the error `Call to undefined function exif_imagetype()`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @phpNoOb I tried as the answer there but still the same error.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Enable the following extensions in `php.ini` and restart your server.

> extension=php_mbstring.dll
>      extension=php_exif.dll

Then check `phpinfo()` to see if it is set to on/off

Comment: --enable-exif #For Linux

Comment: For linux that would be `extension=exif.so`. I could not find an --enable-exif option in the php documentation.

Comment: That is if you compile PHP from source. You can run `--enable-exif` when you --configure /. it @BakaKuna

Answer (score 8):

I think the problem is PHP config and/or version, for example, in my case:

We know [`exif_imagetype()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.exif-imagetype.php) takes a file path or resource and returns a constant like IMAGETYPE_GIF
and `image_type_to_mime_type()` takes that constant value and returns a string `'image/gif'`, `'image/jpeg'`, etc.
This didn't work (missing function exif_imagetype), so I've found that  `image_type_to_mime_type()` can also take an integer 1, 2, 3, 17, etc. as input, 
so solved the problem using getimagesize, which returns an integer value as mime type:

```
function get_image_type ( $filename ) {
    $img = getimagesize( $filename );
    if ( !empty( $img[2] ) )
        return image_type_to_mime_type( $img[2] );
return false;
}

echo get_image_type( 'my_ugly_file.bmp' );
// returns image/x-ms-bmp
echo get_image_type( 'path/pics/boobs.jpg' );
// returns image/jpeg
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your code so as we could know which version of php you do have because this function is only supported by (PHP version 4 >= 4.3.0, PHP 5).

```
<?php 
    phpinfo(); 
?>
```

It may be not installed, you can add this part of code to make sure it is :

```
<?php
if (function_exists('exif_imagetype')) {
    echo "This function is installed";
} else {
    echo "It is not";
}
?>
```

Comment: I am on `PHP Version 5.2.9`.

Comment: @Kishor Subedi, Check my edit , btw are you under windows or linux?

Answer (score 0):

I you use docker, add this to your dockerfile :

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install exif
```