# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function exif_imagetype()

Tags: php, undefined, exif

I got a photo competition that seems to work fine but when I upload a photo I get a blank screen. I checked the error log and found this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function exif_imagetype() in /home/fbtabvhk/public_html/pinkdrive_selfie/contest/libs/upload/save.php on line 27

This is the code on line 27:

```
if (exif_imagetype($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0]) === FALSE)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call to undefined function exif\_imagetype()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16175702/call-to-undefined-function-exif-imagetype)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [have the exif extension compiled and enabled](http://www.php.net/manual/en/exif.installation.php) for this function to work. This extension has good chances to be already compiled in your PHP installation, so you might just have to enable it in your php.ini:

On Linux:

```
extension=exif.so
```

On Windows:

```
extension=php_exif.dll
```

Note for Windows:

> Windows users must enable both the php_mbstring.dll and php_exif.dll DLL's in php.ini.
>   The php_mbstring.dll DLL must be loaded before the php_exif.dll DLL so
>   adjust your php.ini accordingly.

Comment: The ISP Changed the php.ini file and compiled and enabled the exif extension but in an still sitting with the same issue :-( i gave them this thread url so they can see exactly what needs to be done. Any suggestions please?

Comment: They probably forgot to enable it, or to restart the web server. If the output of `var_export(extension_loaded('exif'));` is `false`, the problem is still in their hands!

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable your php.ini and restart server.

```
extension=php_exif.dll
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice will need to contact my ISP don't have access to the php.ini file. will revert back if i am unsuccessful