# How to install/enable php-exif in cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel, exif, whm, exiftool

According to this [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/exif.installation.php) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23978385/8826120) I have to `configure PHP with --enable-exif` and add extension, but the problem is I don't know how to `configure PHP with --enable-exif` and I cannot find the way to edit `php.ini` to add `extension=exif.so`

I don't have WHM credentials and cannot access EasyApache, I only have cpanel user login with limited access..

My php version

```
[user@server ~]$ /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/bin/php -v
PHP 7.3.18 (cli) (built: May 21 2020 03:33:34) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.18, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.3.18, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Is there a way to enable php-exif or should I ask my ISP/Administrator?

Comment: You will need to have ssh access to your server. If it is a shared hosting you should contact your provider. There is no other way you can modify any server related files including php.ini

Answer (score 3):

It seems you don't have full WHM access. 
Php EXIF is generally enabled on most of the servers.
To check if you have EXIF enabled create a PHP file in your cPanel file manager and paste this code in that file:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

then visit that page.
It will show all PHP information. Search for EXIF there. 
If it is disabled then ask your server administrator to enable that for you.