# EXIF Data Error With PHP

Tags: php, gallery, exif, alt

I'm building a website that uses PHP to select all of the images from a folder to be displayed in a gallery.  I also want the image `alt` tag to be the FileName of the photo's EXIF data - So I've developped this script:

```
<?php
$folder = 'cms/galleries/gallery-1/';
$filetype = '*.*';
$files = glob($folder.$filetype);
foreach ($files as $file)
{
    $filedata = exif_read_data($file[$i]);
    if(is_array($filedata) && isset($filedata['FileName'])){
        $filename = $filedata['FileName'];
    } else{
        $filename = explode('.', basename($file[$i]));
        $filename = $filename[0];
    }

    echo '<div class="photoHolder"><div class="photoCell"><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="'.$file.'"><img class="photo" src="'.$file.'" alt="'.$filename.'"></a></div></div>';
}
?>
```

The problem is I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function exif_read_data() in
>   C:\AppServ\www\

I have no idea what this means so can anyone help me with this or ruggest a few minor edits to get this up and running?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16175702/call-to-undefined-function-exif-imagetype/16175827#16175827

Comment: How is this a duplicate? Those questions are nothing like my code

Comment: @eagle12 My previous question wasn't answered, otherwise I wouldn't have had to post this

Comment: @FootPromoter They were answered just like the above. You likely don't have the proper configuration installed to use it.

Comment: @eagle12 I've succesfully extracted EXIF data from images before, just not from a gallery of images like I'm doing now - How stable is the use of PHP exif on a live server?

Comment: @FootPromoter It isn't about stability, it is about whether you have the PHP extension installed or not. The error you have posted indicates that you do not. The question marked as duplicate tells you how to correct the problem. It isn't about the specifics of your code, but the configuration of your PHP instance. Please read the accepted answer at the linked question carefully, and don't focus on the code in the question. Your problem has the same root cause as the problem in the linked question.

Comment: @ChrisBaker - In my ini file both `extension=php_mbstring.dll` & `extension=php_exif.dll` are defined - But I don't know what I'm looking for in the phpinfo file

Comment: @FootPromoter As noted in the linked question, ensure that the exif extension is loaded after mbstring, as the former depends on the latter. You should be able to search your phpinfo output for "exif", if you don't see it then it isn't being loaded. Make sure you're checking the correct php.ini -- some systems have a couple, and you might be checking the one that isn't used! Check the "Loaded Configuration File" value on phpinfo to make sure.

Comment: fwiw, this is what it looks like on my phpinfo: http://i.imgur.com/AGObIvK.png

Comment: Thanks @ChrisBaker - There is no EXIF data in my phpinfo file - I've just moved the `extension=php_exif.dll` to the line beneath `extension=php_mbstring.dll` and restarted the server but there is still no exif information in the phpinfo file

Comment: Okay, tested this on a live server and the photo's show up correctly, however the alt tag now reads `Array` instead of the actual FileName text - Any ideas why this may be? @ChrisBaker

Comment: var_dump the `$filename ` variable and see what it is. Basic debugging -- I can't help you debug your script line by line until it works, it's in your hands. Good luck! :)

Comment: @ChrisBaker Well as the output for that is `array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "c" } `, or in other words `meaningless to me` I guess I'm going to have to find a completely new coding solution!!! Cheers anyway

Answer (score 0):

May be EXIF extension is not enabled. First enable it from php.ini file.

Comment: Both `extension=php_mbstring.dll` & `extension=php_exif.dll` are enabled

Comment: There is no mention of EXIF in my phpinfo file - Why is this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573070/php-exif-read-data-not-defined