# How to use a crop uploader method in PHP?

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, image-uploading

I'm using cropper crop-avatar on [GitHub](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/tree/master/examples/crop-avatar)

In that example, when I'm going to upload an image, I'm getting error in **crop.php on line 40**

Here's error in error log:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function exif_imagetype() in public_html/imagexample/crop.php on line 40

and here's line 40

```
$type = exif_imagetype($file['tmp_name']);
```

How to solve this error?

I tested all image types, like PNG, GIF, JPG, and etc , still same error...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to undefined function exif\_imagetype()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16175702/call-to-undefined-function-exif-imagetype)

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like `exif-support` is not configured with PHP. Check `phpinfo()` to see if it is set to on/off.

You can add exif during php compile by adding `--enable-exif`.

On linux enable exif functions by editing your php.ini file to include `extension=exif.so`, make sure you have the exif.so file in your php modules folder. If not you will need to install it.

On Windows enable the following extensions in `php.ini` and restart your server.

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
```

Comment: I created a file in cpanel php.ini and I save this line --enable-exif inside. but still it's same.

Comment: what about linux hosting server?